# Can't get extra details on Google Places API like 'opening_hours'

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I can't seem to get the opening hours by using google places api.

I used google maps to find a business with hours and rating. I chose a mcdonalds.

[image]

I then used [google's tool](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) to search the place_id of the address.

Which gets me the place_id:

```
ChIJRRNEbiK0xokRxwlEbC1WEqk
```

[image]

Then I try to search for the place details using the place_id

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJRRNEbiK0xokRxwlEbC1WEqk&fields=name,rating,opening_hours&key=MY_KEY
```

but I only get the name, which is set as the address.

[image]

[edit]@geocodezip said that adding 'Mcdonald's' to the beginning of the address returns a different place_id.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That is likely the place id for the address, not the business.  Where did you get the place id from?  BTW, pictures of information are not very useful, they can't be copied and pasted for testing.

Comment: If I enter "McDonald's, 2801 Cottman Avenue, Philadelphia, PA, USA" into [the tool](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id), the place id I get is: "ChIJLZZdbiK0xokRqpqP6w3DRiM"

Comment: @geocodezip Sorry for that. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

That is the place id for the address, not the business.

If I enter "McDonald's, 2801 Cottman Avenue, Philadelphia, PA, USA" into the tool, the place id I get is: "ChIJLZZdbiK0xokRqpqP6w3DRiM"

If I use that id in [your query (with a valid key)](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJLZZdbiK0xokRqpqP6w3DRiM&fields=name,rating,opening_hours&key=), I get a response with the extra data:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "name" : "McDonald's",
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : true,
         "periods" : [
            {
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "0000"
               }
            }
         ],
         "weekday_text" : [
            "Monday: Open 24 hours",
            "Tuesday: Open 24 hours",
            "Wednesday: Open 24 hours",
            "Thursday: Open 24 hours",
            "Friday: Open 24 hours",
            "Saturday: Open 24 hours",
            "Sunday: Open 24 hours"
         ]
      },
      "rating" : 3.1
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle (uses the javascript API places library)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9be7sh4L/24/)

[image: screenshot of fiddle]